# FW/1 - Accessing RC in setupRequest()

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, fw1

I'm using FW/1 ver 3.5.0 with CFM request context (rc) in `setupRequest()` but have been successful. According to the documents (http://framework-one.github.io/documentation/3.5/developing-applications.html#basic-application-structure) I need to add a `before()` in the `application.cfc` and the controller. I must be over looking something, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

> application.cfc

```
function before( struct rc ) {
}
```

> controller

```
function before( struct rc ) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that I wish was better explained was the difference between `setupRequest()` and `before()`

`setupRequest()` happens before `rc` even exists.

`before()` happens after `setupRequest()` is ran and does have access to rc.

An easy way to remember what goes where is. If rc is involved, put it into `before()`. If not, put it in `setupRequest()`

**Note**

This is a change from earlier versions for FW/1. Previously this distinction did not exist. This can be an issue when migrating.

**Also**

You don't need to add a `before()` in `application.cfc` nor in your controller. You only add them if needed. One of the strengths of FW/1 is that most things are optional. If you need something, there will be a place for them.

Comment: Hi James, I did ended up putting my logic in the before() and got everything working. The weird thing is I was able to access the rc in setupRequest() in previous version of FW/1. Anyway thanks for your response.